# Jump to a bookmark+ dired bookmark from Lisp code

Tags: debugging, variables, bookmarks

According to the docu of [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) this code:

```
(bmkp-dired-jump BOOKMARK-NAME &optional FLIP-USE-REGION-P)
```

should allow to quickly jump to a dired buffer that has been bookmarked.

I try to eval `(bmkp-dired-jump d_zh_tmp)`
thinking it should jump to a bookmark called `d_zh_tmp` but instead I get an error:

```
eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: d_zh_tmp
```

Any clue what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bmkp-dired-jump function evaluates its argument; the literal bookmark name therefore needs to be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
(bmkp-dired-jump "d_zh_tmp")
```

Alternatively, you could set the argument equal to a variable, whose value is that string.

```
(setq d_zh_tmp_var "d_zh_tmp")
(bmkp-dired-jump d_zh_tmp_var)
```

Comment: Ye. *All* Emacs-Lisp functions  evaluate all of their arguments. (Some special forms and macros do not evaluate all of their arguments.)

Comment: thx! this works